# How to download files/videos from google drive using Angular 6/7?

Tags: angular, angular7

For the very first time I am trying to use Google drive with my Angular 7 application.
What I want to do is , download a video file from google drive and play it in my Angular Application.
I have googled a lot but didn't got any solution for this kind.
Can anybody please suggest a quick start or tutorial kind of thing which covers over all steps involved in this.
I have created API key and Client ID in my google drive. I just want an approach on how can I use these with Angular 7 to download file/video from google drive.

It would be a great help. Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: show your research efforts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to this question.

1. How do I get files from Google drive with Drive API?

[You will make a GET request following the steps here in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)

1. How do I play a video in the browser?

[You use HTML5 video as described here in W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

I'm not going to write a tutorial for you. This should be more than enough to get you started.